# How is it possible that tv_sec of both timeval structures are the same but subtracting them gives me a non zero value

Tags: c++, c, difftime, timeval

```cpp
timeval end_time;
timeval Dbg_timer;
```

The above time structures where initialized with `gettimeofday()` at some point.

Below is how I calculated the time difference:

```cpp
long int elaspsed_time_s  = end_time.tv_sec - Dbg_timer.tv_sec;
printf("elaspsed_time_s =%d -> end_time_tv_sec=%d  Dbg_timer_tv_sec=%d \n", 
        elaspsed_time_s,       end_time.tv_sec,    Dbg_timer.tv_sec);
```

The Output:

```
elaspsed_time_s =3 -> end_time_tv_sec=1631446699  Dbg_timer_tv_sec=1631446699
```

How is the above possible? What is really going on?

Comment: `long int` `%d`

Comment: I see @KamilCuk okay let me try printing with the right conversions thanks ALOT.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk it turns out I was using the wrong arguments for printing just as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` is not a proper conversion to use for the `long int` value `elaspsed_time_s`. (By the way, the correct spelling is “elapsed”.) Use `%ld` for `elaspsed_time_s`.

`%d` is also not a proper conversion to use for the `time_t` values in the `tv_sec` member. On POSIX systems, `time_t` is an integer type, but it is not necessarily an `int`, as far as I know. To print a `time_t` value, you might convert it to a `long int` and print it with `%ld`:

```
printf("elaspsed_time_s =%ld -> end_time_tv_sec=%ld  Dbg_timer_tv_sec=%ld \n", 
        elaspsed_time_s,
        (long int) end_time.tv_sec,
        (long int) Dbg_timer.tv_sec);
```

Alternatively, you could include `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` and print it via `uintmax_t`:

```
printf("elaspsed_time_s =%ld -> end_time_tv_sec=%" PRIuMAX "  Dbg_timer_tv_sec=%" PRIuMAX " \n", 
        elaspsed_time_s,
        (uintmax_t) end_time.tv_sec,
        (uintmax_t) Dbg_timer.tv_sec);
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric Postpischil the above solved the dilemma printf was just printing the lower bits of the numbers but when I used the correct printf conversion I saw that both numbers where not the same. Thanks alot!!